# Error with Get-Content

Tags: powershell

I have the following portion of code:

```
$fileList | foreach {
Write-Host ". . . adding $_ to script"
$myCreateScript += Get-Content "$ScriptRoot\$_" | Out-String }
```

That produces the following toward the end of execution:

> ItemNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetContentCommand
>   System.Exception: An object at the specified path E:\Scripts\users[[FILE_NAME_LOWER]]_administrator.sql does not exist, or has been filtered by the -Include or -Exclude parameter.

[[FILE_NAME_LOWER]]_administrator.sql is the name of the file, and it does exist in the specified directory. If this is a problem with the fact that the filename contains brackets ([]), I need to know how to resolve it within the foreach block, as I cannot easily change the filenames (they are used elsewhere in code that is in source control) and because of prior code in the script, need to be preserved in $fileList. I suspect the brackets are the issue, because $fileList has over 200 rows, and $myCreateScript gets populated with the correct data up to this point.

Comment: Is the path correct, or should there be a \ after E:\Scripts\users and before the file name?

Comment: typo on my part (I changed path for the post). There is a '\' before the filename.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to use the [`-LiteralPath`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849787.aspx) parameter of `Get-Content`:

```powershell
$myCreateScript += Get-Content -LiteralPath "$ScriptRoot\$_" | Out-String }
```

Otherwise, `[[FILE_NAME_LOWER]]` will be interpreted as a [wildcard character set](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa717088%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which tells PowerShell to match any of the characters enclosed by the two square brackets on each end.